# Counting occurrences of Javascript array indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following array.

```
       "APP-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-C": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-C": {
            "active": true
        },
```

I need to get the total count of the APP-*'s in the array. 
Am trying to implement in angular JS. Solutions in plain JS will also be helpful.

TIA

Comment: That doesn't look like an array.

Comment: `var count = 0; for (var key in obj) count += /^APP-/.test(key)`?

Comment: It doesn't even look like javascript.

Comment: Its a JSON response, needed to fetch count in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/098o3kch/1/

```
var items = { "APP-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-C": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-C": {
            "active": true
        }
};

function getCount(obj,pattern){
var cnt = 0;
 for(var item in obj)
{
if(item.indexOf(pattern) >= 0)  
cnt++;
}
return cnt;
 }

alert(getCount(items, "APP-"));
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `.filter()` on the object's keys:

```
var count = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    return key.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4m692usx/1/

Answer (score 1):

may be try like this:

```
var items = { "APP-A": {
        "active": true
    },
    "APP-B": {
        "active": true
    },
    "APP-C": {
        "active": true
    },
    "BOOL-A": {
        "active": true
    },
    "BOOL-B": {
        "active": true
    },
    "BOOL-C": {
        "active": true
    }
};
var c=0;
for(var item in items)
{
if(item.indexOf("APP-") >= 0)      
c++;
}
console.log(c);// your count here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/yf9sb4yf/)

But actually it's not an array, it's a **JSON object**. And what we are counting is JSON key's.

**JS Part:**

```
var items = { "APP-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "APP-C": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-A": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-B": {
            "active": true
        },
        "BOOL-C": {
            "active": true
        }
};

var app_count = 0;
for(var ik in items) {
    if(ik.indexOf("APP-") >= 0) {
        app_count++;
    }
}
alert(app_count);
console.log(app_count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = {
  "APP-A": {
    "active": true
  },
  "APP-B": {
    "active": true
  },
  "APP-C": {
    "active": true
  },
  "BOOL-A": {
    "active": true
  },
  "BOOL-B": {
    "active": true
  },
  "BOOL-C": {
    "active": true
  }
};

var reg = /^APP-/,
    count = 0, 
    name;

for (name in myArray) {
  count += reg.test(name);
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = count;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a json, not an array.

```
var count = 0;
for (var key in json) {
    key.indexOf('APP-')!==-1?count++,count;
}
```